# App click weather activity's search button, report keeps stopping

Tags: java, android, android-studio

When I click the weather button, it has no any problem, it successfully jumps to my weather activity.
My weather activity has the function that can search the temperature, description, and humidity of the city. However, I click the search button of my weather class, it reports "keeps stopping". Seems like the search button does not work.

LogCat

```
11/23 18:03:18: Launching 'app' on Pixel API 28.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.weather/com.example.groupproject.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 28105 on device 'emulator-5554'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
I/example.weathe: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
W/example.weathe: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86_64
W/example.weathe: Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;->getOpticalInsets()Landroid/graphics/Insets; (light greylist, linking)
    Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->left:I (light greylist, linking)
W/example.weathe: Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->right:I (light greylist, linking)
    Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->top:I (light greylist, linking)
    Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->bottom:I (light greylist, linking)
W/example.weathe: Accessing hidden field Landroid/view/WindowInsets;->CONSUMED:Landroid/view/WindowInsets; (light greylist, reflection)
W/example.weathe: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->getAccessibilityDelegate()Landroid/view/View$AccessibilityDelegate; (light greylist, linking)
W/example.weathe: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (light greylist, reflection)
W/example.weathe: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (light greylist, reflection)
D/OpenGLRenderer: Skia GL Pipeline
W/example.weathe: Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/Insets;->of(IIII)Landroid/graphics/Insets; (light greylist, linking)
D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x72928285a4e0, tid 28200
D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_YUV420_888_to_NV21 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0 
I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay retrieved: 0
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
D/eglCodecCommon: setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0x72928285a760: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x72928285a760: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x72928280dee0)
D/HostConnection: createUnique: call
D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x72928285a9e0, tid 28200
D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_YUV420_888_to_NV21 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0 
E/eglCodecCommon: GoldfishAddressSpaceHostMemoryAllocator: ioctl_ping failed for device_type=5, ret=-1
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x72928285a760: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x72928280dee0)
D/eglCodecCommon: setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 3 2
W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@798fca3
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x72928285a760: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x72928280dee0)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x72928285a760: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x72928280dee0)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x72928285a760: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x72928280dee0)
I/AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 2736 bytes, containing 1 windows, 10 views
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher
    Process: com.example.weather, PID: 28105
    java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:151)
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:105)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1154)
        at okhttp3.Dns$1.lookup(Dns.java:39)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:173)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:139)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:81)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:172)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:123)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:93)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:296)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:248)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponse(RealCall.java:243)
        at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:201)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:163)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.access$100(RealCall.java:30)
        at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:127)
        at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
     Caused by: android.system.GaiException: android_getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
        at libcore.io.Linux.android_getaddrinfo(Native Method)
        at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.android_getaddrinfo(BlockGuardOs.java:172)
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:137)
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:105) 
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1154) 
        at okhttp3.Dns$1.lookup(Dns.java:39) 
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:173) 
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:139) 
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:81) 
        at okhttp3.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:172) 
        at okhttp3.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:123) 
        at okhttp3.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:93) 
        at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:296) 
        at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:248) 
        at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponse(RealCall.java:243) 
        at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:201) 
        at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:163) 
        at okhttp3.RealCall.access$100(RealCall.java:30) 
        at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:127) 
        at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
     Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: android_getaddrinfo failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
        at libcore.io.Linux.android_getaddrinfo(Native Method) 
        at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.android_getaddrinfo(BlockGuardOs.java:172) 
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:137) 
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:105) 
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1154) 
        at okhttp3.Dns$1.lookup(Dns.java:39) 
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:173) 
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:139) 
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:81) 
        at okhttp3.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:172) 
        at okhttp3.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:123) 
        at okhttp3.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:93) 
        at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:296) 
        at okhttp3.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:248) 
        at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponse(RealCall.java:243) 
        at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:201) 
        at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:163) 
        at okhttp3.RealCall.access$100(RealCall.java:30) 
        at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:127) 
        at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x72928285a760: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x72928280dee0)
D/AutofillManager: onActivityFinishing(): calling cancelLocked()
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.groupproject;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btn;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn = findViewById(R.id.button);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, weather.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Weather.java

```
package com.example.groupproject;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.example.groupproject.Retrofit.ApiInterface;
import com.example.groupproject.Retrofit.ApiClient;
import com.example.groupproject.Retrofit.Example;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class weather extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView search;
    TextView tempText, descText, humidityText;
    EditText textField;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_weather);

        search = findViewById(R.id.search);
        tempText = findViewById(R.id.tempText);
        descText = findViewById(R.id.descText);
        humidityText = findViewById(R.id.humidityText);
        textField = findViewById(R.id.textField);


        search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //Here will call the API
                getWeatherData(textField.getText().toString().trim());
            }
        });
    }

    private void getWeatherData(String name) {

        ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

        Call<Example> call = apiInterface.getWeatherData(name);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<Example>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Example> call, Response<Example> response) {

                tempText.setText("Temp" + " " + response.body().getMain().getTemp() + "°C");
                descText.setText("Feel Like" + " " + response.body().getMain().getFeels_like() + "°C");
                humidityText.setText("Humidity" + " " + response.body().getMain().getHumidity() + "°C");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Example> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });



    }

}
```

Main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        android:text="Weather"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Weather.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background = "@drawable/background">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:weightSum="3">


        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2.5"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/textField"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:src="@drawable/search"
            android:id="@+id/search"/>


    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp">



        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Text Temp"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/tempText"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Description"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:id="@+id/descText"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Humidity"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:id="@+id/humidityText"
            />


    </LinearLayout>









</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The exception says it all! ```Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)```. Did you add the internet permission to the manifest?

Answer (score 0):

as I see in your logcat you must add INTERNET permission in manifest.
add this line to your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```